# I need fresh eyes to fix VUE props not working

Tags: vue.js

This is a silly task in VUE.JS... but I'm missing it.

I have a sub parent component having:

```
<teamPlayers :teamId="team.id_team"></teamPlayers>
```

The value **teamId** is sent to the child component and it works: I can see the value in child  template `<h2>{{teamId}}</h2>` properly.

But in same child component I got *undefined* inside the methods using this.teamId.

Here the whole  child code:

```
export default {
    props: ['teamId'],
    methods: {
        getJokess: function () {
            console.log(this.teamId);
        },
    },

    created() {
        this.getJokess();
    }
}
```

The console should return the correct value but it returns *undefined* instead of the {{teamId}} is render perfectly.

Comment: It could be that you are modifying the `team` object in your parent component right after the child component has been created. Try adding a `v-if="team.id_team"` to your child component to check if that's the case.

Comment: hmmm I think this is the right way... thanks! Not yet fixed but if I change parent component having :teamId="2" I got the value 2 in the console!

Comment: How exactly are you using your `teamPlayers` elements?  Is it in a `v-for`?

Comment: @zero298 Yes it's a v-for

Comment: @Ricky oh! Now  I understand what you mean! Using v-if="team.id_team"  it will show the child only after it got the data team... is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it will show the child only after the team object has an id_team property value; then the created life cycle hook will log what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

All that I can think of is that `teams` may not be declared in your `data()` function.  If it isn't it won't be reactive.  Consider the example below:

```js
const teamPlayers = {
  props: ["teamId"],
  methods: {
    getJokess() {
      console.log(this.teamId);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getJokess();
  },
  template: "<h2>{{teamId}}</h2>"
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    "team-players": teamPlayers
  },
  data() {
    return {
      teams: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.teams = [{
          id_team: "fizz"
        },
        {
          id_team: "buzz"
        },
        {
          id_team: "foo"
        },
        {
          id_team: "bar"
        }
      ]
    }, 1000);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="team of teams">
    <team-players :team-id="team"></team-players>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's right. I'll have to fix it. Thanks a lot for your TIME! :D